# copying the files from AWS S3 bucket which are greater than specific date which is tagged to the file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket that contains csv files which has date tagged to the file names in yyyymmdd format. I have a requirement to identify and pull the files greater than specific dates and copy them to my linux instance for data processing through automated process.

Is it possible to pull the files greater than specific dates which are tagged to the filename.

**sample filenames:**

filename_20220101.csv

filename_20220102.csv

filename_20220103.csv

filename_20220104.csv

filename_20220105.csv

filename_20220106.csv

filename_20220107.csv

I want to pull files which are greater than 20220103. Normally the files will be generated on daily basis.

Comment: You can have a look at s3 cli commands and especially the exclude/include filters. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

Comment: You can write a script or program to do this. What is your preferred language?

Comment: I am thinking of writing a python script to implement this logic